# Error: cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I am trying to create a state machine in Verilog, and I am getting these errors:

```
error: reg state; cannot be driven by primitives or continuous assignment.
 error: Port 6 (state) of mealy_machine is connected to state.
```

It says the error is in line 8 of my test bench, so being the instance call of *mealy_machine M1*.

```
module mealy_machine(F, clk, inbits, clear, preset, state);
input clk, inbits, clear, preset;
output reg F;
output reg [1:0] state;

initial begin
  assign state = 2'b00;
end

always @ (posedge clk)
begin //always
    if (clear == 1 && preset == 1)
    begin //if
        begin //case
            case(state)

            2'b00:
            if(inbits)
            begin
                assign state = 2'b00;
                assign F = 1'b1;
            end
            else
            begin
                assign state = 2'b01;
                assign F = 2'b00;
            end


            2'b01:
            if(inbits)
            begin
                assign state = 2'b11;
                assign F = 2'b00;
            end
            else
            begin
                assign state = 2'b10;
                assign F = 2'b01;
            end


            2'b10:
            if(inbits)
            begin
                assign state = 2'b01;
                assign F = 2'b00;
            end
            else
            begin
                assign state = 2'b00;
                assign F = 2'b01;
            end


            2'b11:
            if(inbits)
            begin
                assign state = 2'b10;
                assign F = 2'b01;
            end
            else
            begin
                assign state = 2'b11;
                assign F = 2'b00;
            end
            endcase
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        state <= 2'b00;
        F <= 2'b00;
        if(clear == 0 && preset == 1) 
        begin
            assign state = 2'b00;
            assign F = 2'b00;
        end
        else if (clear == 1 && preset == 0)
        begin
            assign state = 2'b11;
            assign F = 2'b01;
        end
        else if (clear == 1 && preset == 1)
        begin
            assign state = 2'b00;
           assign F = 2'b00;
        end
    end
end
endmodule
```

```
`include "mealy_machine.v"

module mealy_machine_tb();
reg clk, clear, inbits, preset;
reg [1:0] state;
wire F;

mealy_machine M1(F, clk, inbits, clear, preset, state);

initial begin


    $dumpfile("mealy_machine_tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, mealy_machine_tb);
    #10;
    clk = ~ clk;

    #10;
    assign state = 2'b00;
    assign inbits = 2'b00;

    #10;
    assign state = 2'b01;
    assign inbits = 2'b00;

    #10;
    assign state = 2'b10;
    assign inbits = 2'b00;

    #10;
    assign state = 2'b11;
    assign inbits = 2'b00;

    #10;
    assign state = 2'b00;
    assign inbits = 2'b01;

    #10;
    assign state = 2'b01;
    assign inbits = 2'b01;

    #10;
    assign state = 2'b10;
    assign inbits = 2'b01;

    #10;
    assign state = 2'b11;
    assign inbits = 2'b01;

end
endmodule
```

I have read that changing `state` from `reg` to `wire` could help, but then it gives me a big list of errors saying that each `assign` statement in the testbench for the state variable "state is not a valid l-value in mealy_machine-tb"

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple syntax errors in the code:

- You should not declare the `state` signal in the testbench as a `reg` and try to assign any values to it because it is an output port of the `mealy_machine` instance.
- You misused the `assign` keyword in both modules.  There is no need for it.

This code compiles without syntax errors:

```
module mealy_machine(F, clk, inbits, clear, preset, state);
input clk, inbits, clear, preset;
output reg F;
output reg [1:0] state;

always @ (posedge clk)
begin //always
    if (clear == 1 && preset == 1)
    begin //if
        begin //case
            case(state)

            2'b00:
            if(inbits)
            begin
                state = 2'b00;
                F = 1'b1;
            end
            else
            begin
                state = 2'b01;
                F = 2'b00;
            end


            2'b01:
            if(inbits)
            begin
                state = 2'b11;
                F = 2'b00;
            end
            else
            begin
                state = 2'b10;
                F = 2'b01;
            end


            2'b10:
            if(inbits)
            begin
                state = 2'b01;
                F = 2'b00;
            end
            else
            begin
                state = 2'b00;
                F = 2'b01;
            end


            2'b11:
            if(inbits)
            begin
                state = 2'b10;
                F = 2'b01;
            end
            else
            begin
                state = 2'b11;
                F = 2'b00;
            end
            endcase
        end
    end
    else
    begin
        state <= 2'b00;
        F <= 2'b00;
        if(clear == 0 && preset == 1) 
        begin
            state = 2'b00;
            F = 2'b00;
        end
        else if (clear == 1 && preset == 0)
        begin
            state = 2'b11;
            F = 2'b01;
        end
        else if (clear == 1 && preset == 1)
        begin
            state = 2'b00;
           F = 2'b00;
        end
    end
end
endmodule


module mealy_machine_tb();
reg clk, clear, inbits, preset;
wire [1:0] state;
wire F;

mealy_machine M1(F, clk, inbits, clear, preset, state);

always #10 clk = ~ clk;

initial begin
    $dumpfile("mealy_machine_tb.vcd");
    $dumpvars(0, mealy_machine_tb);
    clk=0;
    #10;

    #10;
    inbits = 2'b00;

    #10;
    inbits = 2'b00;

    #10;
    inbits = 2'b00;

    #10;
    inbits = 2'b00;

    #10;
    inbits = 2'b01;

    #10;
    inbits = 2'b01;

    #10;
    inbits = 2'b01;

    #10;
    inbits = 2'b01;

end
endmodule
```

I also moved the `clk` signal in the testbench to its own `always` block because it was always unknown.  You should set all module inputs to known values in the tb.